# Unable to run Selenium tests on CentOS through Xvfb

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline, xvfb

I'm running Selenium tests on `CentOS 7` machine through Jenkins pipeline hence using `Xvfb`. When use `screen` argument with any valid value like following -

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', autoDisplayName: true, screen: '1440x800x8']) { 
   <code to run Selenium test here>
}
```

It results into following error -

```
[testng] org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

   [testng]   (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

   [testng]   (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

   [testng] Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

   [testng] Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
```

If we run it without `screen` argument it runs successfully.

One more observation - with `screen` argument, it perfectly works on `Ubuntu 18`

Please help me how I can run Selenium tests with `screen` argument on `CentOS 7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with different values for `screen` parameters, I realized this is not something which is wrong with Chrome browser or driver but with value passed to `screen`

When I changed depth value from 8 to 16, Selenium execution started successfully - `screen: '1440x800x16'`

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', autoDisplayName: true, screen: '1440x800x16']) { 
   <code to run Selenium test here>
}
```

But technically, I did not understand why this error occurs and how depth value helped to resolve it.